# ThreeJS - Move camera along spline while maintaining orbit control panning

Tags: canvas, three.js, camera, controls, spline

I have a instance of Spline from `THREE.CatmullRomCurve3` with a bunch points. I am able to move my camera up and down the spline when using the mouse wheel just fine.

However, when setting the cameras position on the spline, I lose my OrbitControls rotation/pan. I am wanting to move the camera along a spline with the mouse while while still being able to look around with the cursor.

Anyone have any idea on how to do this? Here is some of the important code:

```
// Increment/Decrement number when scrolling via mouse wheel
let camPosIndex = 0;

canvas.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    camPosIndex += -Math.sign(e.deltaY) * 0.1;
    if (camPosIndex < 0) {
        camPosIndex = 0;
    }
});
```

```
// Animation loop
tick() {
    // Update camera around spline
    if (camera && cameraSplinePoints.length > 0 && cameraSpline) {
        const camPos = cameraSpline.getPoint(camPosIndex / 100);
        const camRot = cameraSpline.getTangent(camPosIndex / 100);

        camera.position.x = camPos.x;
        camera.position.y = camPos.y;
        camera.position.z = camPos.z;

        camera.rotation.x = camRot.x;
        camera.rotation.y = camRot.y;
        camera.rotation.z = camRot.z;

        // Somewhere above or below, the camera is now ignoring the orbitcontrols panning.

        camera.lookAt(cameraSpline.getPointAt((camPosIndex+1) / 100));
    }

    // Update controls
    controls.update()

    // Render
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    // Call tick again on the next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}
```

Comment: If you're using OrbitControls, you could have the `.target` property move along the spline. That way the focus of the camera moves, but you retain control over the orbiting. [See here](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=orbitc#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.target)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it would by setting the target to the camera position and looking in its direction.

In my render loop, I set the position and rotation via:

```
controls.object.position.set(camPos.x, camPos.y, camPos.z);

controls.target = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(
    controls.object.position,
    controls.object.getWorldDirection()
);
```